# Example/Reference needed for Laplace equation coupled with another equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, problem-solving, laplacian, coupling

I have been trying to solve a heat-exchanger problem where two fluids are separated by a conducting wall between them and the fluids flow perpendicular to each other. So i need to consider two dimensional conduction in this separating wall while heat gets exchanged between the two fluids through this wall.

Are there any examples of analytic solution to a Laplace equation coupled with another ODE ? I have failed to find any such example. Most texts deal with variants of the Laplace operator with different bc(s).

Comment: I don't think you can get closed form solutions for coupled problems like the one you describe. Just for testing purposes you can choose a function satisfying the boundary conditions and add source terms to the pde's so that this function is the actual solution. The problems will be coupled through the boundary conditions.

Comment: @PierreCarre Have a look https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093821/suitable-ansatz-for-coupled-system-of-pdes